# Movie\show with futuristic soldiers and a flashback scene

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

So I keep having flickering memories of this movie or TV show from my childhood. Circa early 1990s I'm thinking.

There's one scene in particular that I remember, where a man is being questioned by what I remember to be a man in a suit.  I believe he is undergoing some sort of psychological testing.  The man in the suit asks the other person a question, and keeps telling the person being questioned "don't think, act". And as he is doing this, he is leaning forward with his elbows on his desk twirling/moving a pen around in front of his face with both of his hands.

The man being questioned appears to have a vision or a flashback to a gloved hand over a hole, dropping what appears to be some sort of grenade into it.  The flashback view is a first person view from someone in a hole/underground tunnel, looking upward at the hole and the hand dropping the bomb/grenade.  That's all I remember!  If you know what movie this might be, let me know!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for an episode of [Space: Above and Beyond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_Above_and_Beyond), a short-lived FOX show from the 90s about futuristic soldiers in space. In episode 13:

> After experiencing an anomalous precognition which saved the lives of the 58th, Damphousse is investigated by a colonel in charge of the Psi Corps. The colonel is convinced that she possesses psychic powers and deduces that only true mortal danger activates Damphousse's precognition.

The vision Damphousse has involves a gloved hand tossing a grenade down a tunnel. The colonel who talks to her later [(Richard Kind)](http://static.cinemagia.ro/img/db/actor/00/01/54/richard-kind-722177l.jpg) explains that time is a circle by twirling a pen in front of her face with both hands. He then tests her precognitive abilities with [flashcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_cards) while continually saying to her "Don't think, act!" The episode is [available on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8sOqZSDkVo) (the pen bit starts around 15:30).

Comment: I loved that show